# Workaround for fast test of GWT app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gwt

I started a GWT project targeted for iPhone (and later for other mobile platforms). Now there's a problem:
* I can use Safari on iOS to test it, but I have to compile my app which takes a while even after performance optimizations mentioned for example [how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler);
* I can NOT use Safari in gwt-debug mode to make quick tests without compilation Java to JS because there's no GWT plugin for Safari on iOS.

So: is there a workaround for fast test of GWT app on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. I have been developing a GWT app using PhoneGap to bring it to iOs and Android. I ended up just using Firefox for development, every once in a while letting the app run in the iOS Simulator (coming with XCode). But since the app is using geolocation via PhoneGap, there was no way around installing it on the phone every once in a while to make sure it behaves.

I found some mobile dev emulators, one that is coming to my mind is called [Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/). There are others out there, but non of them worked for me.

Comment: Just stumbled over this list of mobile emulators and simulators... http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators

Comment: For latest iOS sdk (5.0+) you can put geolocalization code as emulator setting on launch, so it becomes a problem of a less size for you. For me, I just abandoned this idea for a while.