# Do all GWT browsers have a 2 connection limit?

Tags: http, gwt

We have a GWT app which implements a Server Push technique to allow the server to notify the client of events. In Internet Explorer 7 we experience some performance issues which we believe to be caused by the 2 connection limit.

Reading this article http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=ServerPushFAQ under the section **2 Connection Limit** is the statement

> All GWT-compatible browsers will only make 2 connections to 1 server

Is this true? I thought most modern browsers would allow 6 connections - Is there some additional constraint on the number of open connections imposed by GWT that will restrict it to 2 even if the browser will support 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT does not impose any limit (note that it says "GWT-compatible browsers", not "GWT"); it's just that this doc is out of date (and the whole "incubator" project deprecated, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers (2009 and later) make 6 connections per server. It's certainly possible that GWT itself imposes a limit on XHR/AJAX calls made using their APIs to avoid blocking behavioral differences across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer from versiuon 5 to to  has a two connection limit See:

- [The Dreaded 2 Connection Limit](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/11/the-dreaded-2-connection-limit/) (a comment form Anders Both not the most reliable sopurce i know...)
- [Browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=1) (if it is working)

You can try to only compile not for IE 6 and 7 (See: [How do I speed up the gwt compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler))

The other posibilty would be to host them on different domain names, which would allow tow connections to each domain name, as stated in your article:

> A google maps application could for example load the map images from img.maps.google.com instead of maps.google.com. The browser would perceive the two hosts as different and thus allow 2 connections to each, even if they both resolve to the same IP address (=go to the same physical server machine).