# What options are available to speed up the GWT compiler

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I speed up the gwt compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler)

I work on a GWT project where the debug mode is not useful, thanks to the incredible amount of time it takes to parse JSON responses from a REST service (we're talking 5 minutes to parse one average response in debug mode, as opposed to a second or two when compiled).

However, the time it takes to compile a GWT project is also becoming unacceptable. So what can be done to speed up the GWT compile process?

Comment: Have you tried [Super Dev Mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode)? Also try `AutoBean` for JSON processing, or [Elemental](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/elemental)'s JSON (they will parse JSON in the JVM in DevMode, rather than in the browser, no JSNI involved)

Comment: Super Dev Mode does look like an awesome solution to these issues, but I have yet to actually try it. When I do I'll post some numbers here though.

Answer (score 7):

[How do I speed up the gwt compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler) has a good selections of tips for speeding up the GWT compilation process, so I thought I'd share some of my results.

- Default options: 4:29.868s
- [User agent "chrome"](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml): 2:32.370s
- [collapse-all-properties](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations): 2:47.146s
- [draft compile](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/ReleaseNotes_2_0#NewFeaturesDraftCompile) & User agent "chrome": 2:10.726s
- [draft compile](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/ReleaseNotes_2_0#NewFeaturesDraftCompile) & collapse-all-properties: 2:24.548s

**NOTES**

Setting the user agent requires

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent'/>
```

and

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
```

to be set in your whatever.gwt.xml module file. Otherwise you'll get the error

```
[ERROR] Property 'user.agent' not found
```

The -draftCompile option needs to be set as a JVM variable in Eclipse as

```
-Dgwt.draftCompile=true
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add also: <set-configuration-property name="user.agent.runtimeWarning" value="false"/>. W/o this, when ran from Firefox we get: Uncaught Error: Class$S15: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml module file.
The compile time user.agent value (safari) does not match the runtime user.agent value (gecko1_8).
Expect more errors.