# Pass draftCompile to IntelliJ IDEA's GWT compiler

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, gwt2, intellij-14

With the [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) it is possible to pass the [`draftCompile`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#draftCompile) flag to the GWT compiler.

How can I pass this parameter to IntelliJ IDEA's internal GWT compiler to speed up the compilation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `File > Project Structure > Facets`, select your GWT facet and add this to your `compiler parameters`:

```
-draftCompile
```

Sources:

- [draftCompile](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#draftCompile)
- [GWT Facet page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gwt-facet-page.html)

Comment: It seems like you have to pass `-draftCompile`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler/2758588#2758588 and https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/gwt-compiler-options/

Comment: I updated my answer. I wasn't sure, because the GWT Facet page says: "In this text box, specify the options to be passed to the GWT compiler process in the format of a command line.". But I think, this makes more sense.

Comment: I think the boolean value after the parameter is wrong.