# Compiling GWT project throws out of memory exception

Tags: gwt

Did you manage to compile GWT application with maven build with increased memory. I am having similar issue and not able to compile GWT project.

I have 64 bit Windows OS and 8 GB RAM. At the moment ,I use devmode to deploy GWT project which takes around 30 min in Jetty and for every small change we have to repeat this exercise again. We waste around 3-4 hours in building GWT application everyday, quite frustrating for a developer!! GWT version 2.5.1

I am looking for a solution on how to compile GWT project. I have tried all different setting in my pom.xml i.e.

```
<disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
  <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
  <enableClosureCompiler>true</enableClosureCompiler>   
  <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
  <localWorkers>2</localWorkers>
  <soyc>false</soyc>
  <optimizationLevel>6</optimizationLevel>
  <extraJvmArgs>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms768m -Xmx2048m -Dgwt.jjs.permutationWorkerFactory=com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -server</extraJvmArgs>
```

Still no luck !! I would be really grateful if somebody could help here! Regards, Subodh

Comment: You could try to reduce the number of permutations

Comment: `-Xmx2048m` says you are giving it 2gb, why not give it more? Also consider reducing localWorkers to 1, so that it doesnt need to do 2x the work at once (thus using more ram).

Comment: This [stackoverflow post][1] has great info for how to speed up your compile. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler

Comment: Thank you Colin,  I am using STS(Spring) 64 bit IDE and using GWT pluging    https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/archive/3.2.4/3.6    .      I am trying to launch GWT Compile project in the IDE and getting this heap error. I tried increasing memory more than 2gb but it doesn't allow as it's 32 bit plugin. Any idea how to increase this memory or use 64 but GWT plugin for IDE ? I have already tried other options like compiling for 1 permutation but it didn't help