# Launching GWT Super Dev Mode is very slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I upgraded my application to `GWT 2.7` version and used Super Dev Mode, but it's taking almost 5 minutes to launch the application in SDM:

```
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: C:\Users\SAM~1.IND\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-8409402920962843736.tmp
   Loading Java files in com.example.ex.onlineexample.Result.
   Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to DEBUG or WARN to see all errors.
   Ignored 27 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Module setup completed in 297949 ms
2015-08-18 11:10:26.902:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-08-18 11:10:27.383:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9876

The code server is ready at http://localhost:9876/
```

297949 ms = 4.96582 minutes, its almost taking 5 minute. Is there anything I need to correct? Any Suggestion? How to minimize this time?

Comment: any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try the following to decrease compile time:

- Give more RAM to the SuperDevMode-JVM (e.g. by adding `-Xmx1024M` as a JVM parameter).
- Remove all unnecessary libraries (check all `<inherits />` tags) and code (check all `<source />` tags) from your module's `.gwt.xml` file. Everything that isn't compiled doesn't take time.

Furthermore, you should consider [all answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler) showing how to minimize the compile time of GWT.