# GWT application not working correctly in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt

In my application i am using GWT 2.4 with gxt-2.2.6-gwt22.jar and jqwidgets componenets. When i run my application in google chrome, mozilla firefox , internet explorer 11, the application works correctly without any problem. But when i run the application in internet explorer 9 (ie9) the UI gets modified in an unevenly manner, also any gwt rpc and gwt request builder calls are not functioning. Totally the application is NOT WORKING in ie9.

I have compiled my gwt application for all browsers. But it is not working. My client wants to run the application in IE9 only.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [GWT IE9 guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9.html)? Please check that ie6 permutation is being compiled in your App.gwt.xml module XML file - check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011877/339219.