# How to run tomcat7-maven-plugin, that server code changes will be updated immediately

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have project in maven. Here is main `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>shared</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.webport>8083</tomcat.webport>
        <tomcat.ajpport>8182</tomcat.ajpport>
        <tomcat.context>/parent</tomcat.context>

        <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>

        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.182</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Custom formats -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.extended</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <defaultGoal>clean install tomcat7:run-war-only</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>  <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
                    <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                    <ajpPort>${tomcat.ajpport}</ajpPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using `tomcat7-maven-plugin` as You can see in pom.xml.

To start server I use command: `maven clean install tomcat7:run-war-only`

But unfortunately when I do any change in **server side/tier code** I have to stop server and run it again, which takes a lot of time, cause of: test runs, full compilation, all permutation compilation (it is gwt app, so it compiles java code to js code for each web browser)...

How can I set up auto code replace/hot swap on runtime, that I don't have to restart and recompile my project, when I do one little change?

I would speed up my developing process.

Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the bit which takes the longest is the GWT complication. If you are doing all your development with a single browser, you can tell GWT to only compile the permutation for that browser. See [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011863/how-do-i-speed-up-the-gwt-compiler) to see how. That should cut down your build time.

Also, you can tell Maven to skip tests. This is not really a practice I'd recommend, but if you are really sure your change is trivial, or does not involve Java code, then use the Maven switch `-DskipTests`

If you change only involves resources such as HTML, CSS, JS, JSP etc then you can just copy them directly to $tomcat_home/webapps/yourapp and Tomcat will pick them up, no build needed. Take care to always have the newest version in your source code.

Finally, the Tomcat plugin should not require a Tomcat restart. Try

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy
```

Comment: I should use this command: `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` when I have running tomcat server? Will this update my java classes on server?

Comment: I am getting an error: `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'redeploy' in plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0 among available goals exec-war-only, deploy-only, shutdown, run-war-only, run, deploy, run-war, exec-war, help -> [Help 1]
`

Comment: Strange. Try `mvn tomcat7:deploy` instead. Tomcat should be running. It will update whole application on Tomcat. Automatically runs `package` first, so will recompile everything.

Comment: Dosen't work. Maybe we should continue on chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90302/how-to-runn-tomcat7-maven-plugin-that-server-code-changes-will-be-updated-immedi?

Comment: I have a working pom with tomcat plugin, but it's on my pc at home - I'll edit my answer later with the working plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat7-maven-plugin is not made for that purpose, use an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans,...) or a dynamic classloader like JRebel.

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE. But I don't know how to integrate Tomcat Maven plugin with Eclipse Servers. Can You give me some thoughts about it? Is it possible? What do You mean by: `Use IDE`?

Comment: Eclipse already has an ability to publish resources to a server. No need to use the Plugin explicitly. Open "Windows" -> "Views" -> "Servers". Add your Tomcat and a Project and press play. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftomcat.html

Comment: I've tried to do this. Unfortunately my Maven project doesn't work with Eclipse servers. How should I configure Maven or Eclipse to make them work together?

Comment: I know what IDE is. I'just can not make them two work together. Maven starts his own eclipse server using maven goals. Please help me on that.